# RedirectToAction where the Controller is in an Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting started with ASP.Net core MVC 3.1 and have an area called *Foo*:

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Foo",
    areaName: "Foo",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

And in this area a controller called *Test* with an *Index* action: `https://localhost:44390/Foo/Test/` - this works fine.

I'm trying to redirect to this from another controller with

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test", new { area = "Foo" });
```

but this is sending me to `https://localhost:44390/Test?area=Foo`

How can I use `RedirectToAction()` to end up at `https://localhost:44390/Foo/Test/` ?

Comment: Can I ask what `area:exists` is supposed to be doing, should this not just be `{area}`?

Comment: Its documented as *exists applies a constraint that the route must match an area*

Comment: I think you must leave out the `area` from the route pattern: `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. Then `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test", new { Area = "Foo" });` should work.

Comment: Try to define new `MapRoute` and use `RedirectToRoute` instead of `RedirectToAction`

Comment: If I remove the {area:exists} then it works (matches on the controller name presumably) but it still displays the Area as a querystring and would also allow https://localhost:44390/Test/

Comment: try this
`endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Foo",
    areaName: "Foo",
    pattern: "Foo/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
`

Comment: Same behaviour as currently.

Comment: The reason it's allowing `localhost:44390/Test` is because you have defaults on controller and action thought right?

Comment: try this `return Redirect(Url.Content("/area/controller/action"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your problem when `MapAreaControllerRoute` is placed after the default route.So, to resolve it, your area route config must go at first place.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
               name: "Foo",
               areaName: "Foo",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
           );
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

put these attributes in the Test Controller.

```
[Area(nameof(Foo))]
[Route(nameof(Foo) + "/[controller]")]
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIzlT.png)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should below code:

```
namespace Solution.Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers
{
    [Area(nameof(Foo))]
    [Route(nameof(Foo) + "/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index() => View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

set route in **Configure**:

```
"{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

then

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test", new { area = "Foo" });
}
```

then

```
[Area("Foo")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```